# how to replace image of imageview in lollipop?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here i am facing a problem regarding android v5(lollipop). The common method
Imageview.setImageResource(//id) happily work with below android v5(lollipop), but not work in lollipop, so please suggest me your knowledge regarding this

Comment: need your suggestion please reply if you know otherwise please dont make it minuse

Comment: your question is not quite clear. Without having posted code or logcat or any error. We are not `Super Human`

Answer (score 0):

imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_resource); is added in api level 1. Please read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) in the official Android documentation. Maybe you're doing something else wrong, but this method is okay to use in Android Lollipop.

You should also post your code, maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Thnk you brother for your advise , but i could not find this error beacause of same apk i run in two device one has android v4.3 and second has v5.1.0 , and apk is work successfully work in v4.3 and same side not work in v5.1.0 how?

Comment: Well then what happens? How come it doesn't work? Do you take your resource from your drawable folder? Are you sure you don't have a drawable folder just for android lollipop and above and thus it doesn't find it?

Comment: @DDsix How did you know about an issue? Wait until OP posted some relavent code or give some msg for posting a code or error otherwise flag such questions with `No having posted code` This is the way of SO.

Comment: even i can get imageview clicklistner toast but could not replace it.

Comment: @DDsix-- i replace this image from resource. and every drawble folder having same images so about the resolution that might not any issue.. But i get surprised with this issue without any exception or error.

Comment: @ M D I don't know if you have read my answer, but I asked OP to post code. I just told him that the method exists in api 21+ and it should work fine and that the problem is somewhere else. I'm not sure what you problem is, anyway :)

Comment: hey brother ... i got the problem .. i am using
if(Word1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.img9).getConstantState())

for compare two drawable .. that is not work in v5.

Comment: ya i am sorry ...for this. now any other method that can work for compare two drawable one from given imageview and another from resource?

Comment: Those are different bitmap objects, I don't know if it will work because they are different instances, thus aren't equal. You should use a different approach